EmptyRecyclerView cannot be cast to android.widget.ListView
Hy i am making an android app and using RecyclerView for showing list of steels. i am using EmptyRecyclerView which extends RecyclerView so that i can use setEmptyView. when I go to the activity that should be listing steels elements in recyclerview I get this error
EmptyRecyclerView cannot be cast to android.widget.ListView
here is my code
DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(getApplicationContext());
        ArrayList<Steel> steelsList = db.retrieveSteels();
        EmptyRecyclerView recyclerViewSteels = (EmptyRecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_steels);

        if (!steelsList.isEmpty()) {
            findViewById(R.id.empty_view).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            steelsListAdapter = new SteelsListAdapter(steelsList);
            recyclerViewSteels.setAdapter(steelsListAdapter);
        } else {
            recyclerViewSteels.setEmptyView(findViewById(R.id.empty_view));
            findViewById(R.id.empty_view).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

the error is pointing to this line
if (!steelsList.isEmpty()) {
can someone please help me . thanks in advance
i add dependecies for recyclerview in gradle i tought that is what was missing but i got no solution
this is the xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_steels"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
            android:background="#4F5EB1"
            android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/editTextNumber_steel_id_steels"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:title="@string/steelsList"
            app:titleTextColor="@android:color/white" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editTextNumber_steel_id_steels"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:hint="@string/steelId"
            android:importantForAutofill="no"
            android:inputType="number"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/editTextTextPersonName_steel_type_steels"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar_steels"
            tools:ignore="TextContrastCheck,TextContrastCheck" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editTextTextPersonName_steel_type_steels"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:hint="@string/steelType"
            android:importantForAutofill="no"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/spinner_steel_geometric_shape_steels"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editTextNumber_steel_id_steels"
            tools:ignore="TextContrastCheck,TextContrastCheck" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner_steel_geometric_shape_steels"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="51dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/editTextNumberDecimal_steel_weight_steels"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editTextTextPersonName_steel_type_steels"
            tools:ignore="SpeakableTextPresentCheck,SpeakableTextPresentCheck,SpeakableTextPresentCheck" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editTextNumberDecimal_steel_weight_steels"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="49dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/weight"
            android:importantForAutofill="no"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/editTextTextPersonName_steel_unit_steels"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/spinner_steel_geometric_shape_steels"
            tools:ignore="TextContrastCheck,TextContrastCheck" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editTextTextPersonName_steel_unit_steels"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:hint="@string/unit"
            android:importantForAutofill="no"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/list_view_steels"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editTextNumberDecimal_steel_weight_steels" />

        <com.example.metalconstructionsestimates.arraysadapters.EmptyRecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler_view_steels"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="370dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editTextTextPersonName_steel_unit_steels" />

        <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/empty_view"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="245dp"
                android:text="@string/noEstimates"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"/>

        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab_clear_steel_form"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:backgroundTint="#4F5EB1"
        app:tint="@color/fabIconTint"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_revert" />

    <!-- Add FAB -->
    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab_add_steel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/fab_clear_steel_form"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:backgroundTint="#4F5EB1"
        app:tint="@color/fabIconTint"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_add" />

    <!-- Search FAB -->
    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab_search_steels"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/fab_add_steel"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:backgroundTint="#4F5EB1"
        app:tint="@color/fabIconTint"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

here is the code for EmptyRecyclerView class
import android.content.Context;

import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
public class EmptyRecyclerView extends RecyclerView {
private View mEmptyView;
public EmptyRecyclerView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public EmptyRecyclerView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public EmptyRecyclerView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

private void initEmptyView() {
    if (mEmptyView != null) {
        mEmptyView.setVisibility(
                getAdapter() == null || getAdapter().getItemCount() == 0 ? VISIBLE : GONE);
        EmptyRecyclerView.this.setVisibility(
                getAdapter() == null || getAdapter().getItemCount() == 0 ? GONE : VISIBLE);
    }
}

final AdapterDataObserver observer = new AdapterDataObserver() {
    @Override
    public void onChanged() {
        super.onChanged();
        initEmptyView();
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemRangeInserted(int positionStart, int itemCount) {
        super.onItemRangeInserted(positionStart, itemCount);
        initEmptyView();
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemRangeRemoved(int positionStart, int itemCount) {
        super.onItemRangeRemoved(positionStart, itemCount);
        initEmptyView();
    }
};

@Override
public void setAdapter(Adapter adapter) {
    Adapter oldAdapter = getAdapter();
    super.setAdapter(adapter);

    if (oldAdapter != null) {
        oldAdapter.unregisterAdapterDataObserver(observer);
    }

    if (adapter != null) {
        adapter.registerAdapterDataObserver(observer);
    }
}

public void setEmptyView(View view) {
    this.mEmptyView = view;
    initEmptyView();
}

}

Can you share the xml where the id recycler_view_steels is defined?

You'll need to show the code from your custom recyclerview

ok thank you i will show it when i go home
